# How to add CSS file to all pages - magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

Currently, I am using a custom theme and my parent theme is **LUMA**.

I need to add `custom.css` file which should be available in all pages.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create **Magento_Theme/layout** folder in your custom theme if not created.

Then create **default_head_blocks.xml** file.

and put following content.

default_head_blocks.xml (By putting content in this file, It will be added to throughout the site)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Add some style to your custom.css and flush cache then check.

You want to go for a page specific for e.g. for product detail page only then you've to edit **Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

And add following content in it

```
<head>
   <css src="css/product-view.css"/>
</head>
```

It's recommended to use **LESS**  file for styles.

You just need to create a **LESS** file and Magento will automatically compile it for you, If you are not in Production Mode and Cache is disabled.

Comment: I have added   <css src="css/my_style.css"/> code in default_head_blocks.xml of the main LUMA theme just for testing before making changes in main site.

And then created my_style.css in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-Luma/Magento_theme/web/css/

Now i'm getting this error => Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/my_style.css'

Comment: Changing directly in LUMA theme is not recommended. Please make changes in your custom theme only.

Answer (score 4):

You can just create **default.xml** file inside `app/design/frontend/{Packaname}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>    
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css"/>      
    </head>
</page>
```

Set your `custom.css` file

```
app/design/frontend/{Packaname}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/web/css/custom.css
```

Run php magento cache:clean command